# CSS before selector fill available space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Is there a way to make a before selector fill the right side of space that is free and leave the left side untouched?

[image: Example]

I want the red line to fill the right side of available space, is it achievable?

```
.grey {
    border-left:1px solid #d1d1d1;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}

    .grey:before {
        content:'';
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:red;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-99;
    }
```

I'm using Bootstrap RC2.
The `.grey` class is added to a `col-4` div.

I want the left side of the screen to be untouched, but the right side to be filled with the "red" color.
The color should start from the `col-4` div.

Comment: Can you make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you have so far?

Comment: @thirtydot http://ggawp.eu/demo/

Comment: space after Recent Activity or space including Recent Activity ?

Comment: @AdityaSaxena After and or including both will work. But not before Recent Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using calc()

Sample **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vEvdF/1/)**

```
.container:before{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(((100% - 1170px)/2));
}
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know there's a calc() property in CSS, or is it a hack?

Comment: It's a new function in CSS 3 - take a look at the [Values and Units Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#calc-notation) for more about it. Also take a look at [this chart](http://caniuse.com/calc) for browser support.